# jquery-ui hides chrome scrollbar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome, datepicker, scrollbar

I am using jquery datepicker. Since Google Chrome 20 the vertical scrollbar gets hidden on any page using the datepicker.

I've tried setting 
    body {
        overflow-y: scroll;
        height: 100%;
    }
Doing this displays an empty vertical scrollbar (nothing to drag) and scrolling is still impossible with mouse-wheel, keys etc.

I'm pretty sure this is a jquery vs Chrome 20+ conflict.

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: OK, I was able to resolve this by setting html{ overflow-y: auto; } body {overflow:scroll;}